# how to remove duplicate values from Array using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello im beginnger in javascript also in react. can somebody help me to solve this. i just try this project from reactjs blog but i just wanna try solve this with my way

todoList.js

```
const todoList = [
    {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
    {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
    {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
    {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
    {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
    {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

export default todoList
```

FilterTableProdcTable.js

```
class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const aw = []
        todoList.forEach(elem=>{
            if(aw.indexOf(elem.category) === -1){
                aw.push(
                    <li key={elem.name}> {elem.category}</li>
                )
            }
        })

        return(
            <div>
                {aw}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the result still same, all duplicate values still show on my screen. can somebody help me?

im sorry about my broken english, but thank you all

Comment: Dont some categories have different items though? How would they be duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be fine, the only problem is that your `aw` array is getting filled with `li` attributes, they are not strings that contain the `elem.category`. Perhaps if you kept track of different arrays, you could check the indexOf that. There's also the `innerHTML` or `textContent` you could use on the `li` attributes. Maybe consider something like this:

```
const aw = [];
const categories = [];
todoList.forEach(elem=>{
    if(!~categories.indexOf(elem.category)) { // tilde changes the result of indexOf to a boolean
        aw.push(
            <li key={elem.name}> {elem.category}</li>
        )
        categories.push(elem.category)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const uniqueTodos = todoList.filter((todo,index) => {
  return index === todoList.findIndex(obj => {
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(todo);
  });
});
```

Also change your data.  There is nothing unique in that dataset.

Also, this code will remove objects only if they are identical with all properties.  It can be adapted to only consider one property.

```
const uniqueTodos = todoList.filter((todo,index) => {
      return index === todoList.findIndex(obj => {
        return obj.category === todo.category;
      });
    });
```

```
class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const aw = []
        uniqueTodos.forEach(todo => {
             aw.push(<li key={todo.name}> {todo.category}</li>)
        })

        return(
            <div>
                {aw}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Also I have changed your dataset a little bit to test it.

```
const todoList = [
    {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
    {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: true, name: 'Basketball'},
    {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: true, name: 'Basketball'},
    {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
    {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
    {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'}
];

export default todoList
```